# How to create this structure using arrays / dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays

I am a newbie an am unable to find the solution of how to create this sort of structure:

```
{ 
  "rohan": ["apple","banana"], 
  "aman": ["pineapple","banana"], 
  "ram": ["apple","grapes"]
}
```

The case is to store fruits liked by some students in a school; the intention is to make this. What is the best possible way?

Comment: For proper Python syntax, replace the outer-most brackets with curly brackets.

Comment: Research Python dictionaries - that is the structure you are looking for. If you replace the outer brackets with curly brackets you will actually have properly declared one in Python.

Comment: you can learn about dictionary in python by https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp. what you need is a dictionary with list value for each key!

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments mentioned a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) would be the best way to organize this data.

You would store the `fruits` in a dictionary (notice the `{}`) with the key being the type of fruit and the value being a `list` of students associated with that fruit.

```py
fruits = {'apple':['rohan','ram'], 'pineapple':['aman'], 'banana':['rohan','aman'], 'grapes':['ram']}
```

You could then easily grab the data you needed let's say for example every student who likes apples.

```py
print(fruits['apple']) 
# ['rohan', 'ram']
```

You can read more on dictionaries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can make such type of structure in Python using lists inside a dictionary (the one having curly brackets). So you can write your code like:

```
students_like_fruits = {
    "rohan": ["apple","banana"], 
    "aman": ["pineapple","banana"], 
    "ram": ["apple","grapes"]
}
```

Where, the student names are keys and the fruits liked by them are the values of each key.

Answer (score -1):

```
dictionary = {}
While True:
---input01 = input("Keys")
---input02 = input("vals")
---dictionary[input01] = input02
```

Comment: You should explain your answer rather than providing just the code.